# При асинхронном вызове поле с [ThreadStatic] атрибутом содержит значение уже закрытого потока

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть сервер на основе TcpListener. Он принимает входящие подключения асинхронно 
 в `BeginAcceptTcpClient (AsyncCallback, Object)` и при инициализации клиента сохраняет значение в поле
`[TreadStatic]
static bool initialize;`
           и назначает имя потоку в котором ведется обработка клиента
Но иногда при подключении нового клиента эта переменная уже содержит значение, а имя потока содержит информацию из прошлых разорванных подключений. 
Правильно ли я предполагаю, что поток для обработки нового клиентского сокета берется из пула и возвращается туда после разрыва этого подключения и то, что данные потока остаются до следующего использования?
Какой способ можно предпринять чтобы видеть для нового подключения в потоке данные по-умолчанию?

Comment: Да,  правильно. Потоки переиспользуются, и вы видите старые значения.

Comment: Так сделайте откат данных при закрытии соединения

Comment: Тащемта, у асинхронных операций не должно быть обращений к одному статическому полю. Есть контекстный AsyncLocal, может вам хватит его?

Comment: Атрибут `ThreadStatic` выглядит очень привлекательно, что бы его использовать. Но по-моему, это все таки признак плохого дизайна кода. Вы сами не можете связать свои объекты, и хотите возложить эту отвественность на атрибут. А если использовать, то только с потоками созданными вручную через `new Thread()`